# linux GNU getopt: ignore unknown optional arguments?

Tags: linux, bash, getopt

Is it possible to ignore unknown optional arguments with GNU getopt?

I have a script, scriptA.sh, that has optional arguments `--optA, --optB, --optC, --optD`.

I would like to write a wrapper, wrapperA, with two optional arguments, `--optX and --optY`, that calls `scriptA`.  However, I don't want to declare all optional parameters of scriptA inside the wrapper.

In particular, if inside `wrapperA`, I specify optional arguments with

```
getopt --longoptions optX:,optY:
```

the call

```
wrapperA --optX --optA --optB
```

returns an error

```
getopt: unknown option -- optA
```

Can GNU getopt be forced to ignore unknown arguments and place them after the '--' in its output?

Answer (score 6):

It is not possible to tell GNU getopt to ignore unknown options. If you really want that feature you will have to write your own option parser.

It is not as simple as to just ignore unknown options. How can you tell whether an unknown option takes an argument or not?

Example usage of original script:

```
originalscript --mode foo source
```

here `foo` is an argument to the option `--mode`. while `source` is a "non-option parameter" (sometimes called "positional parameter").

Example usage of wrapper script:

```
wrapperscript --with template --mode foo source
```

How can getopt in `wrapperscript` know that it should ignore `--mode` together with `foo`? If it just ignores `--mode` then `originalscript` will get `foo` as first positional parameter.

A possible workaround is to tell the users of your wrapper script to write all options intended for the original scrip after a double dash (`--`). By convention a double dash marks the end of options. GNU getopt recognizes double dash and stops parsing and returns the rest as positional parameters.

See also:

- http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/dict/terms/end_of_options

Comment: Thank you for your response.  Double dash to terminate option list will work in my case.  As for ignoring unknown options, I see your point - it is not as easy as it looks.  My original idea was to push all unknown options behind -- in getopt output (--with template -- mode foo source).  However, this would work only if subsequent parameter handling is handed off to the originalscript. As you said, wrapperscript has no way of knowing if parameters of originalscript take arguments.

Comment: Had a similar problem, the double dash works as a charm.

Answer (score 1):

I was working on a similar thing, and found this to work to stop getopt errors from bugging me with these errors. Basically just pipe the errors to oblivion.

```
while getopts "i:s:" opt > /dev/null 2>&1; do
    case $opt in
      i)
        END=$OPTARG
      ;;
    esac
done
./innerscript $*
```

$ ./blah.sh -s 20140503 -i 3 -a -b -c

Comment: **This breaks if the missing argument takes an `OPTARG`**. https://gist.github.com/cirosantilli/2a803442add75e0f1e164cde183999d3 GNU Bash 4.3.48.

Comment: This also breaks if the invalid option(s) is(are) passed *before* the valid ones.

Comment: The question is specific to 'getopt' not built in 'getopts'

Answer (score 0):

For `getopt`, at least for one from util-linux-2.37.2, STDERR can be ignored or --quiet flag can be used:

```
$ getopt --quiet --options=c: --longoptions=component -- --component value --foo
--component -- 'value'
```

Note that exit status will still be 1, as validation of arguments can’t be done by `getopt`, as it can’t know that what kind of errors you want to ignore.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to just ignore stderr, appending `2>dev/null` to the starting line of `while` as below is OK. I think you can use this also for `getopt`.

```
while getopts "a:p:" opt 2>/dev/null
do
    case $opt in
      \?)
        echo "any error comment you want" 1>&2
        exit 1
        ;;
    esac
done
```

Comment: The question is specific to 'getopt' not built in 'getopts'

Answer (score -2):

Well, I could work around the problem. The idea involves fiddling with `OPTIND` when facing an unknown option, so that the parsing could be continued by `getopts`. Consequently we would need to keep where we were are at parsing so that `OPTIND` can be adjusted accordingly.

```
local parse_index=1 # initialize to cater for the first option coming out unknown
while getopts ':m:t:r:u:p:' opt; do
  case $opt in
    m) build_module="$OPTARG"
       parse_index=$OPTIND
       ;;
    t) build_tag="$OPTARG"
       parse_index=$OPTIND
       ;;
    r) container_registry="$OPTARG"
       parse_index=$OPTIND
       ;;
    u) registry_username="$OPTARG"
       parse_index=$OPTIND
       ;;
    p) registry_password="$OPTARG"
       parse_index=$OPTIND
       ;;
    :) echo "Option -$OPTARG requires an argument" >/dev/stderr
       ;;
   \?) echo "Unknown option: -$OPTARG"
       ((OPTIND = $parse_index + 2))    # fool `getopts` to continue parsing
       parse_index=$OPTIND      # adjust to cater for successive unknown options
       ;;
  esac
done
```

I have used an assumption that encountered unknown options would follow by an argument so the part `((OPTIND = $parse_index + 2))`, adapt to your own case. The assumption proves brittle and non-inclusive, but works under those circumstance. Also note that still it discontinues in case of an error (missing argument).

Apparently, not a general and clean approach, nevertheless helped overcome the situation where no other alternative found.

Comment: The question is specific to 'getopt' not built in 'getopts'